# Google map custom tiles not working in Android P

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

I am using Goole Map's `TileOverlay` to overlay custom tiles in the application to show heatmap. For Android 8.0 and below heatmap is shown perfectly but for 9.0 map shows patchy tiles (tiles are custom .png images).

```
gradle version:    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

Code to overlay: `TileOverlay overlay = gMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider).fadeIn(false));`

[image][image]

Comment: hey @Isham have you got any solution over TileOverlay ?
I am ussing OpenstreetMap in that till 7.1.1 TileOverlay  is working fine above that versionits not loading tiles...

Comment: I raised it with Google maps team and they have agreed this is a major bug from their side. Waiting for the fix. I will update it here.